# How to use async and await in p5 with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I'm using https://github.com/and-who/react-p5-wrapper to have p5 in my React file.
I've a question about doing things asynchronously.

So in my Sketch file, instead of

```
p5.keyPressed = () => {
...
...
bunch of chaining setTimeout (..., 1000)
}
```

Can I do,

```
async p5.keyPressed = () => {
...
...
await p5.delay(1000)
}
```

What's the right syntax to do this?

Comment: you await something that returns a Promise - so `const delay=ms=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, ms))` - then you can `await delay(1000)` ... but it'd be `p5.keyPressed = async () =>` not what you wrote

Comment: Oh nice, so instead of `p5.keyPressed = () => ` it should be `p5.keyPressed = async () =>` thanks!

Comment: well, yes, because the function needs to be async ... not the property (which is a syntax error)